# How to install jrnl on git bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I am trying to have the "jrnl" command line application installed in my git bash, but I couldn't manage to do it. Is it possible to have it installed somehow? I am running Windows 10 at the moment.

The jrnl application I am mentioning is this one:
https://jrnl.sh/en/stable/

The git bash I am using is this one:
https://git-scm.com/downloads

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [the installation instructions](https://jrnl.sh/en/stable/installation) ? What happened?

Comment: BTW, "git bash" is just bash; it doesn't have anything to do with git except that the people who make the Windows installer for git include it in the same package. It's more accurately called "msys bash" (as msys is the library and build toolchain used to make it compatible with Windows). Thus, it's better to use the `git-bash` tag instead of the `git` one.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way! I did not know about pipx. As soon as I got it installed, I was able to run:
`pipx install jrnl`

Then I configured this in my .bashrc:
`alias journal='winpty jrnl'`

After that I just had to restart my git bash, using jrnl through the "journal" command.

`journal at 8pm: done`

Thanks

Comment: Note that in general, aliases are better replaced with functions. Functions work in scripts by default whereas aliases don't; they can be exported to be available to subprocesses; and you can do conditional logic inside them. `journal() { winpty jrnl "$@"; }` is a function with the same functionality and usage as the alias above (but you can put it in a script and it'll work).